# Create a DOM DocumentFragment from Range with CSS Styles Applied

Tags: javascript, html, dom, webkit

Suppose a document like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .my-bold {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>

<p id="first">Paragraph with <span class="my-bold">bold text</span></p>
<p id="second">Another Paragraph with <span class="my-bold">bold text</span></p>
```

I'd like to extract the second paragraph with styles applied:

```
<p id="second">Another Paragraph with <span class="my-bold" style="font-weight: bold">bold text</span></p>
```

Is there an API for this? I tried Range.cloneContents()

```
var p = document.getElementById( "second")
var range = document.createRange()
range.selectNode( p)
var html = range.cloneContents()
```

But this gives me only the HTML without styles:

```
<p id="second">Another Paragraph with <span class="my-bold">bold text</span></p>
```

A WebKit-only solution would be sufficient.

Comment: You can't do it *directly* but you can try to read the styles for each element inside the `p` element and place it in the `style` attribute. `var span=p.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];span.setAttribute('style',window.getComputedStyle(span, null));` **MIGHT** work. I didn't tested this!!! Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle for documentation on that method.

Comment: Aside from my previous comment, the tag [tag:webkit] isn't necessary here, since it had nothing to do with `webkit`itself.